# Transforming vertices results in texture issues

Tags: three.js, 3d

I'm having an issue in Three.JS that I was hoping someone would be able to help me with. I'm pretty sure this is to do with my lack of knowledge in the areas of both Three.JS and 3D so it may be relatively simple (or complex) I'm not sure.

So I have an object that's a table and I've got it coming into 3D space and it looks fine.

[image: Underside of table]

Now, in my application, I have the option to update the length/width of the table. I do this by taking each vertex position and moving it in the x or z-axis by a set amount. This works fine. The issue is the textures aren't mapping on correctly after this transformation.

[image: Underside of the table with obvious texture skewing on the edges]

These issues are creeping in where multiple faces are meeting. I thought it was a 'normals' issue and have tried both recomputing the Face and Vertex normals on the object using the built-in functions for Buffer Geometries. I also tried computing them on my own - my changes weren't reflected on the table so I'm fairly confident I've been doing this wrong.

If anyone could lend some insight into why this is occurring I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Is your mesh subdivided such that there are multiple polygons between the table edge and the inner surface? In other words, rather than having that area be 1x1 and scaled, the area is, say, 10x20. When you scale this surface, it could potentially be scaling and skewing the internal triangles, causing your mesh to become inconsistent. But since the UVs don't change, they cause the texture to map in a non-uniform manner.

Comment: @TheJim01 Yes. There are multiple polygons on the edges of the texture and each of the mismatches is occurring across them. Do you have any insights into what I'd need to do in relation to the UV's in order for them to match the scaled object? Thanks for the response. It's much appreciated.

Comment: First ensure that they're scaled uniformly. This means If you have 10 polygons that are 2 units tall, and you shrink the whole shape to 10 units tall, each polygon should become 1 unit tall. If that happens, then the texture should also scale uniformly. But if your vertices scale linearly (as if one side scales faster than the other), you may see this kind of warping.

Comment: I don't think that would work for me in this case. I need to be able to scale the object in a non-uniformed way. I know this is going to cause the initial UV's to be incorrect. What I need to know is how to change the UV coordinates to reflect this so the textures wrap correctly?

Comment: Since you don't have uniform scaling, you'll need to figure out where in the UV map the vertex should sit, given its new position. Remember that UVs are just percentage references to positions on the texture, so if you can calculate the percentage change in position, you should be able to apply the same transformation to the UV.